# text inputs don't change when option changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/43/

The problem I have is with the text inputs not changing. Please follow steps in fiddle below so you can see what is happening:

1. When you open fiddle, click on the "Add Question" button, this will add a table row copying the controls from the top into the table row.
2. In the table row click on the "Open Grid" and select button 5. You will see 5 letter buttons appear underneath from A-E.
3. Turn on all of the letter buttons by clicking on them (They should turn green to symbolize that the button is turned on)
4. You will see right at the bottom of the fiddle that it shows all of the text inputs of each value of the buttons which are turned on. This is fine.
5. The problem is here. If you go back into the table row and click on the "Open Grid" link again but this time choose "3", you will see the letters buttons change to A-C. Now letters D and E are not shown so they are turned off. But problem is that if you go to the bottom of the fiddle, the text input form D and E are still shown, they should be removed.

So my question is: **what needs to be changed in the fiddle so that when the user changes their option type, it only displays the text inputs of those buttons which are still on after option has changed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you choose a option your code cleans the number box and the letters get changed ok.

The logic you apply to letters with class 'answerBtns answers' need to be apply also to the letter at the bottom. You must apply a class and do de process in javascript when get another choose.

Comment: Do you think I am better off making a new function which deals with "answerBtns answers" or just apply it in the original function? Do you have any ideas what is best way to edit the fiddle for it to work?

Comment: If I realized correctly the fields at the end of the page will be used only when you submit the form.
Maybe you should consider fill it when you needed, so no matter what users are doing, only need the final result.

if it is necessary to update the field I prefere have an identifier for each group and a javascript function that receives the group field ID and handle it